# JavaScript handler to seek to one of several locations

Tags: javascript

How would I simplify the following function to reduce repetitive code? I would like to define "arg" as an array since that is the only changing aspect of each case.

```
  function jumpMovement(iMovement) {

        switch (iMovement) {
            case 0:
                document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage('{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"0.0"}', 'https://musescore.com');
                break;
            case 1:
                document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage('{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"99.45"}', 'https://musescore.com');
                break;
            case 2:
                document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage('{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"201.45"}', 'https://musescore.com');
                break;
            case 3:
                document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage('{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"319.49"}', 'https://musescore.com');
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage('{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"0.0"}', 'https://musescore.com');
        }
    }
```

Sample of use in html:

```
 <button onclick="jumpFigure(0)">0</button> &nbsp;
 <button onclick="jumpFigure(1)">1</button> &nbsp;
 <button onclick="jumpFigure(2)">2</button> &nbsp;
```

etc...

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, our goal here is to help you improve your code by making insightful observations about the code that is written. The code must be working as intended already. We don't answer `How to ...` questions because that means the code isn't working as intended yet. There is a site that can help you, Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The simple answer is that you have a variable that is updated by the switch statement, you use that variable to complete the post message statement after the switch statement has updated the variable.

Comment: I am confused about the criteria. The code I submitted does work as intended. My question was about making it more economical. Regardless, according to your link, it appears that stackoverflow.com is more suited to this type of question.

Comment: Looking over other javascript questions in the Code Review forum, I've come across other similar, but non-closed, questions, looking for feedback on economizing code. What makes my question different from others such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278429/simplify-a-function-which-performs-manipulation-of-data-in-javascript or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278346/grouping-objects-in-a-javascript-array-by-category-and-counting-them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely remove the switch (assuming that `iMovement` can be used as an index).

If `iMovement` is going to have a much wider spread of values, then you can use a switch and just set `arg` accordingly, then make the DOM call at the end.

```
function jumpMovement(iMovement) {
    const args = [ 0.0, 99.45, 201.45, 319.49 ]
    const arg = args[iMovement] ?? 0.0

    document.getElementById('opus-08a').contentWindow.postMessage(`{"method": "seekSeconds", "arg":"${arg.toFixed(2)}"}`, 'https://musescore.com');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly the kind of help I was looking for.