# Simplify a function which performs manipulation of data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, functional-programming

Upon suggestion in the original question within Stack Overflow, I'm bringing my question here.

We have created a function that will convert the data into the desired format, but it has a lot of code and is difficult to understand. If a new person has seen this code means, it's very hard for them to know the functionalities.

below is the code for it

```js
const data = [{"id":"Client 1","advisorName":"Dhanush","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Thor Odin","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":0.855,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"id":"goal-1","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Retirement1","goalAmount":10000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"22/1/2022","score":0.99},{"id":"goal-2","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":70000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"55/45","lastModified":"5/12/2023","score":0.72}]},{"id":"Client 2","advisorName":"Dhanush","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Steve Rogers","goalName":"Save for Investment","goalAmount":67000,"goals":1,"score":0.7,"lastModified":"22/1/2022","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"id":"Client 3","advisorName":"Dhanush","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Wanda Vision","goals":0,"score":0.9,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":""},{"id":"Client 4","advisorName":"Dhanush","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Tony Stark","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":0.29,"lastModified":"27/10/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"id":"goal-4","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Education Loan","goalAmount":500,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"27/10/2019","score":0.29},{"id":"goal-5","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"House Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"16/6/2022","score":0.29}]},{"id":"Client 5","advisorName":"Joe","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Hack Eye","goalName":"Save For World Tour","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":0.74,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"60/40"},{"id":"Client 6","advisorName":"Joe","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Nick Fury","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":0.44499999999999995,"lastModified":"9/3/2022","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"id":"goal-7","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"To Build A Workspace","goalAmount":42340,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/3/2022","score":0.6},{"id":"goal-8","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Cloud Examination","goalAmount":8730,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":0.29}]},{"id":"Client 7","advisorName":"Joe","managerName":"Nikolai","clientName":"Star Lord","goalName":"Save For Child Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":0.93,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"55/45"},{"id":"Client 8","advisorName":"Pal","managerName":"Rohan","clientName":"Thanos","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":3,"score":0.29,"lastModified":"2/11/2019","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"id":"goal-10","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Relocation Expense Goal","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"22/78","lastModified":"2/11/2019","score":0.29},{"id":"goal-11","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Save for to buy bike","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"50/50","lastModified":"1/1/2020","score":0.29},{"id":"goal-12","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"65/35","lastModified":"9/5/2022","score":0.29}]},{"id":"Client 9","advisorName":"Pal","managerName":"Rohan","clientName":"Ego","goalName":"Save For Education","goalAmount":400000,"goals":1,"score":0.72,"lastModified":"","equityFixedIncome":"65/35"},{"id":"Client 10","advisorName":"Pal","managerName":"Rohan","clientName":"Bruce Banner","goalName":"","goalAmount":"","goals":2,"score":0.975,"lastModified":"9/10/2018","equityFixedIncome":"","subRows":[{"id":"goal-14","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Car Loan","goalAmount":23000,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"60/40","lastModified":"9/10/2018","score":0.99},{"id":"goal-15","clientName":"","managerName":"","advisorName":"","goalName":"Bike Loan","goalAmount":4600,"goals":1,"equityFixedIncome":"30/70","lastModified":"9/11/2021","score":0.96}]}]

function firstLevelRestructure(data){
  return data.reduce(
    (acc, row) => {
      if (row.advisorName !== acc.level1.clientName) {
        let newRow1 = {
          advisorName: row.advisorName,
          managerName: row.managerName,
          id: "",
          clientName: "",
          goalName: "",
          goalAmount: "",
          goals: "",
          score: "",
          lastModified: "",
          equityFixedIncome: "",
          subRows: [],
        };
        acc.result.push(newRow1);
        acc.level1.clientName = row.advisorName;
        acc.level1.arr = newRow1.subRows;
      }
      let newRow2 = {
        advisorName: "",
        managerName: "",
        id: row.id,
        clientName: row.clientName,
        goalName: row.goalName,
        goalAmount: row.goalAmount,
        goals: row.goals,
        score: row.score,
        lastModified: row.lastModified,
        equityFixedIncome: row.equityFixedIncome,
      };
  
      if(row.subRows) {
        acc.level2.arr = newRow2.subRows = [];
      }
      acc.level1.arr.push(newRow2);
  
      if (row.subRows) {
        row.subRows.forEach((subRow) => {
          acc.level2.arr.push({ ...subRow });
        });
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {
      result: [],
      level1: { clientName: "", arr: null },
      level2: { arr: null },
    }
  ).result;
}



const restructure = (data, keyName) => {
  let val = firstLevelRestructure(data)
  const emptyNode = {
    managerName: "",
    advisorName: "",
    id: "",
    clientName: "",
    goalName: "",
    goalAmount: "",
    goals: "",
    score: "",
    lastModified: "",
    equityFixedIncome: "",
    subRows: [],
  };
  
  const groups = val.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item[keyName]] ??= [];
    acc[item[keyName]].push({ ...item, [keyName]: "" });
    return acc;
  }, {});

  return Object.entries(groups)
    .map(([keyValue, subRows]) => (
        { ...emptyNode,  [keyName]: keyValue , subRows }
    ));  
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(restructure(data, 'managerName')));
```

And why am doing this conversion because, we are creating a multi level nested row expansion table which requires this kind of structure. You can get the working demo link here - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-1t77ks?file=/src/styles.css

[image]

And the structured data will be used to create the table with the expansion like in the above image.

Here u can see the formatted data - https://codesandbox.io/s/tanstack-table-expansion-1t77ks?file=/src/data/table-data.json

Instead of calling the function `firstLevelRestructure` Is there a way to use the function `restructure` to handle it?

I am in need of your help to solve this. Please let me know the feasibility of that.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 7 → 5. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: As the moderator @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ indicated yesterday please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should work on the spirit of information synthesis, it should help you get a simpler way of coding

```js
const data = [{id:'Client 1',advisorName:'Dhanush',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Thor Odin',goalName:'',goalAmount:'',goals:2,score:0.855,lastModified:'22/1/2022',equityFixedIncome:'',subRows:[{id:'goal-1',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Retirement1',goalAmount:10000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'60/40',lastModified:'22/1/2022',score:0.99},{id:'goal-2',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Save For Child Education',goalAmount:70000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'55/45',lastModified:'5/12/2023',score:0.72}]},{id:'Client 2',advisorName:'Dhanush',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Steve Rogers',goalName:'Save for Investment',goalAmount:67000,goals:1,score:0.7,lastModified:'22/1/2022',equityFixedIncome:'60/40'},{id:'Client 3',advisorName:'Dhanush',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Wanda Vision',goals:0,score:0.9,lastModified:'',equityFixedIncome:''},{id:'Client 4',advisorName:'Dhanush',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Tony Stark',goalName:'',goalAmount:'',goals:2,score:0.29,lastModified:'27/10/2019',equityFixedIncome:'',subRows:[{id:'goal-4',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Education Loan',goalAmount:500,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'60/40',lastModified:'27/10/2019',score:0.29},{id:'goal-5',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'House Loan',goalAmount:23000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'30/70',lastModified:'16/6/2022',score:0.29}]},{id:'Client 5',advisorName:'Joe',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Hack Eye',goalName:'Save For World Tour',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,score:0.74,lastModified:'',equityFixedIncome:'60/40'},{id:'Client 6',advisorName:'Joe',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Nick Fury',goalName:'',goalAmount:'',goals:2,score:0.44499999999999995,lastModified:'9/3/2022',equityFixedIncome:'',subRows:[{id:'goal-7',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'To Build A Workspace',goalAmount:42340,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'60/40',lastModified:'9/3/2022',score:0.6},{id:'goal-8',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Cloud Examination',goalAmount:8730,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'30/70',lastModified:'9/11/2021',score:0.29}]},{id:'Client 7',advisorName:'Joe',managerName:'Nikolai',clientName:'Star Lord',goalName:'Save For Child Education',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,score:0.93,lastModified:'',equityFixedIncome:'55/45'},{id:'Client 8',advisorName:'Pal',managerName:'Rohan',clientName:'Thanos',goalName:'',goalAmount:'',goals:3,score:0.29,lastModified:'2/11/2019',equityFixedIncome:'',subRows:[{id:'goal-10',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Relocation Expense Goal',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'22/78',lastModified:'2/11/2019',score:0.29},{id:'goal-11',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Save for to buy bike',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'50/50',lastModified:'1/1/2020',score:0.29},{id:'goal-12',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Save For Education',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'65/35',lastModified:'9/5/2022',score:0.29}]},{id:'Client 9',advisorName:'Pal',managerName:'Rohan',clientName:'Ego',goalName:'Save For Education',goalAmount:400000,goals:1,score:0.72,lastModified:'',equityFixedIncome:'65/35'},{id:'Client 10',advisorName:'Pal',managerName:'Rohan',clientName:'Bruce Banner',goalName:'',goalAmount:'',goals:2,score:0.975,lastModified:'9/10/2018',equityFixedIncome:'',subRows:[{id:'goal-14',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Car Loan',goalAmount:23000,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'60/40',lastModified:'9/10/2018',score:0.99},{id:'goal-15',clientName:'',managerName:'',advisorName:'',goalName:'Bike Loan',goalAmount:4600,goals:1,equityFixedIncome:'30/70',lastModified:'9/11/2021',score:0.96}]}]

const
  nodOrder = 
    { managerName: '',  advisorName: '', clientName: '', id: ''
    , goalName: ''   ,  goalAmount: '',  goals: '',      score: ''
    , lastModified: '', equityFixedIncome: ''
    } 
, levels = 
    { managerName: { arr: null, val: '' }
    , advisorName: { arr: null, val: '' }
    , clientName:  { arr: null }
    }
, ResultData = []
  ;
data.forEach( ({ managerName, advisorName, ...otherProps }) => 
  {
  let
    row_0 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { managerName })
  , row_1 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, { advisorName })
  , row_2 = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, otherProps )
    ;
  if (levels.managerName.val !== managerName )
    {
    levels.managerName.val = managerName 
    levels.managerName.arr = row_0.subRows = []
    levels.advisorName.val = ''
    ResultData.push( row_0 )
    }
  if (levels.advisorName.val !== advisorName )
    {
    levels.advisorName.val = advisorName 
    levels.advisorName.arr = row_1.subRows = []
    levels.managerName.arr.push( row_1 )
    }

  levels.clientName.arr = (otherProps.subRows) ? (row_2.subRows = []) : null
  levels.advisorName.arr.push( row_2 )

  if (otherProps.subRows) 
    {
    otherProps.subRows.forEach( subRow => 
      {
      let sRow = Object.assign({}, nodOrder, subRow )
      levels.clientName.arr.push( sRow )
      })
    }
  })
console.log( ResultData )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Nice reorganization. In retrospect, renaming for meaningful variables (my pet peeve) at the same time would make the code restructuring itself harder to appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

**it has a lot of code and is difficult to understand**

1. What business entities, or DB tables perhaps, do "row" and "subrow" represent?
2. The objects are shredded down to their properties and put into two different objects of exactly the same schema as the object they were ripped from.
3. What is "acc"? It is the transformed data objects I guess, so what it that?
4. Names "newrow1" and "newrow2" and "row" suggest these are all the same kind of thing - the same business entity; the same DB table object; the same Class; because they are all "rows" - like identical twins having identical DNA (object definition/structure) each with half of the other's own data.

**What is the data schema?**

Name variables/objects for the business entities they represent.

That "row" data is ripped in half into "newrow1" and "newrow2" hints to me that they should be different classes/objects with only the properties appropriate to each.

**Code to reflect data structure**

I have no idea what an `arr` is but I think `[ ]` and `{ }` is less error prone than `null` - and is more consistent with initialization in other parts of the code. And no need to test for null before iterating, adding to, etc.

In my opinion the code is too clever by using `reduce`. It obscures the data structure and transformations. I generally prefer separate methods for building parts of the data structure. That will clearly show the data structure and data relations.

"Methods/functions will be too small", not worth the effort you might say. Try it and see if it doesn't meet your goal: *If a new person has seen this code means, it's very <strike>hard</strike> easy for them to know the functionalities*.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. I agree that my question has a lot of grey areas that are difficult to understand. Am working on that to explain the details furthermore.